SQL SSIS job failing
I have a SQL Server 2022 application running on 2 nodes redundantly, one of the jobs (SSIS) is failing on the primary node saying the service account can not find the specified file, the exact same job, works fine on the secondary node using the same service account (domain account). Job works fine when running through visual studio using the same domain account (SQL Server Agent account)
I can browse into the path were the job file is stored from both nodes using the service account. I recreated the job by using the script from the job that works fine but still no success. I copied the SSIS package file locally into the server but i still have the same issue. any ideas? Thanks in advance!

The process could not be created for step 1 of job 0x72DB1C3372A2974DAA7D83AED24F078F (reason: The system cannot find the file specified).  The step failed.

USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Job [UPLOAD]    Script Date: 4/11/2024 12:25:14 PM ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]    Script Date: 4/11/2024 12:25:14 PM ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'UPLOAD', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=2, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', 
        @notify_email_operator_name=N'Administrator Group', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [1step]    Script Date: 4/11/2024 12:25:14 PM ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'step 1', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=N'/FILE "\"\\[PATHTODRIVE]\jobs\ssis_job.dtsx\"" /X86  /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'Update Scores', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=0, 
        @active_start_date=20240328, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=63000, 
        @active_end_time=235959, 
        @schedule_uid=N'01xxx58-4xxxb-4xxxx-861f-9dxxxx0xx1'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:
GO





I assume you're using UNC paths?

"i can browse into the path were the job file is stored from both nodes using the service account" wait, are you using a file deployment method? Why aren't you using SSISDB?

yes unc paths. Dev team created the job not me, it randomly stopped working, the package source is file system.

Same user on both? Same Proxy account, if used?

@billinkc same domain user on both, no proxy account.

"The process could not be created" sounds like it can't find or access the file that the job depends on. What is the job definition?

@Charlieface i can access the file using the user from both nodes and I can map it as a network location.

@billinkc script for job added

Posting a temporary answer, as I think this is going to be a permission/user error but want to see how things are set up on your end
We get similar scripts for running an SSIS package on the file system

Let's see if we can tease out some more information. Create this job on both nodes.
DECLARE @jobId binary(16);
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name = N'CMD Debugging'
,   @enabled = 1
,   @notify_level_eventlog = 0
,   @notify_level_email = 0
,   @notify_level_netsend = 0
,   @notify_level_page = 0
,   @delete_level = 0
,   @description = N'No description available.'
,   @category_name = N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
,   @owner_login_name = N'sa'
,   @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
    @job_id = @jobId
,   @step_name = N'DBG - where dtexec'
,   @step_id = 1
,   @cmdexec_success_code = 0
,   @on_success_action = 3
,   @on_success_step_id = 0
,   @on_fail_action = 2
,   @on_fail_step_id = 0
,   @retry_attempts = 0
,   @retry_interval = 0
,   @os_run_priority = 0
,   @subsystem = N'CmdExec'
,   @command = N'where dtexec.exe'
,   @flags = 32;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
    @job_id = @jobId
,   @step_name = N'DBG - whoami'
,   @step_id = 2
,   @cmdexec_success_code = 0
,   @on_success_action = 3
,   @on_success_step_id = 0
,   @on_fail_action = 2
,   @on_fail_step_id = 0
,   @retry_attempts = 0
,   @retry_interval = 0
,   @os_run_priority = 0
,   @subsystem = N'CmdExec'
,   @command = N'whoami'
,   @flags = 32;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
    @job_id = @jobId
,   @step_name = N'DBG - network path'
,   @step_id = 3
,   @cmdexec_success_code = 0
,   @on_success_action = 1
,   @on_success_step_id = 0
,   @on_fail_action = 2
,   @on_fail_step_id = 0
,   @retry_attempts = 0
,   @retry_interval = 0
,   @os_run_priority = 0
,   @subsystem = N'CmdExec'
,   @command = N'DIR "\\erech\C$\tmp\so_58775698\output\ETL\Step1.Load"'
,   @flags = 32;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job
    @job_id = @jobId
,   @start_step_id = 1;

It should run 3 OS Command job steps.
The first is where dtexec that is going to identify, in order, the paths to the program that actually runs SSIS packages.
The second command is slightly redundant but it is whoami which returns the domain name of the current user. Redundant as the execution of the job steps will also include this but I find explicit intentions helpful
The third command is a request to list the contents of a directory. DIR "\\erech\C$\tmp\so_58775698\output\ETL\Step1.Load" where the network path will be what you have in your actual job.
Run the job and then on each server, let's look at the output.
SELECT SJH.step_id, SJH.run_time, SJH.server,  SJH.message
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS SJH
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS SJ WHERE SJ.name = 'CMD Debugging' AND SJ.job_id = SJH.job_id)
AND SJH.step_id > 0
ORDER BY SJH.run_time;

I see something like the following
1   115043  ERECH\DEV2017   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
1   115043  ERECH\DEV2017   Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$DEV2017. The step succeeded.
1   115406  ERECH\DEV2017   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe
1   115406  ERECH\DEV2017   Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$DEV2017. The step succeeded.
2   115407  ERECH\DEV2017   nt service\sqlagent$dev2017
2   115407  ERECH\DEV2017   Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$DEV2017. The step succeeded.
3   115407  ERECH\DEV2017    Volume in drive \\erech\C$ has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3AB8-1C01

 Directory of \\erech\C$\tmp\so_58775698\output\ETL\Step1.Load

08/17/2020  10:08 AM    <DIR>          .
08/17/2020  10:08 AM    <DIR>          ..
08/17/2020  08:50 AM               163 BimlScript.biml
08/17/2020  08:47 AM    <DIR>          bin
08/17/2020  08:47 AM                65 Project.params
08/17/2020  08:51 AM               639 SO.63451166.dtsx
08/17/2020  08:47 AM             1,251 Step1.Load.database
08/17/2020  08:47 AM             2,710 Step1.Load.dtproj
08/17/2020  10:08 AM               563 Step1.Load.dtproj.user
08/17/2020  08:51 AM               638 Step1.Load.dtsx
               7 File(s)          6,029 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  167,191,408,640 bytes free
3   115407  ERECH\DEV2017   Executed as user: NT Service\SQLAgent$DEV2017. The step succeeded.

It's messy, there are embedded carriage returns in the output but I can tease out that the first dtexec is 150. That might be an issue as this instance is 2017 but I assume the actual SSIS jobstep has more brains in it to not get crossed up on dtexec versions. But, we at least find a dtexec on the path.
Step 2, the redundant piece shows a whoami of nt service\sqlagent$dev2017 I suspect this is going to be different between your two nodes
Step 3, this will show off the file contents. I can confirm that yes, I see Step1.Load.dtsx which is the package I am attempting run on this UNC path. In the event the sql agent job fails on step 3 on the server that can't also find the package, I expect to see output like "The system cannot find the path specified." in your log.
If we get that, and there are 2 different accounts listed on step 2, then we know that either we have folks responsible for PATHTODRIVE server grant list/read permissions for the account specified OR you change the account that runs SQL Agent jobs to mirror the one that is able to access the file share.
